# Enviar por POST variables javascript fuera de un formulario

Tags: javascript, php, post

Tengo un modal que al abrirlo se cumplimentan todos los datos para enviarlos por POST a una página php donde por medio de fpdf los visualizo. El caso es que hay cuatro campos, marca, modelo, color y matrícula que voy añadiendo filas cada vez que le doy a agregar vehículo (todo esto dentro del form), pero a la hora de enviar el formulario estos datos no se pasan:

Mi form dentro de un modal:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Depósito de vehículo</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <form action="imprimir/veh_entrada.php" method="POST" name="your_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input name="operacion" value="save_vehiculo" id="operacion" type="hidden">
                    <input name="jef" value="<?php echo $max_jef; ?>" id="" type="hidden">
                    <input name="agente_1" value="<?php echo $usuario; ?>" id="" type="hidden">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>JEF nº:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Fecha y hora:</label>
                            <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="birthdaytime" name="birthdaytime">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Marca:</label>
                        <select name="marca[]" id="marca" class="form-control">
                            <option value="Alfa Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
                            <option value="Aston Martin">Aston Martin</option>
                            <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
                            (...)
                            <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                            <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Modelo:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modelo" name="modelo[]">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Color:</label>
                            <select name="color" id="color" class="form-control">
                                <option value="Rojo">Rojo</option>
                                <option value="Verde">Verde</option>
                                <option value="Azul">Azul</option>
                                <option value="Amarillo">Amarillo</option>
                                <option value="Blanco">Blanco</option>
                                <option value="Negro">Negro</option>
                                <option value="Naranja">Naranja</option>
                                <option value="Violeta">Violeta</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Matrícula:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="matricula" name="matricula" placeholder="Formato 1234-XXX">
                        </div><br>
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="agregar">Agregar</button>
                        </div>
                        <br>

                        <table width="100%"> <!--tabla donde voy añadiendo vehículos -->
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Marca</th>
                        <th>Modelo</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Matrícula</th>
                        <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="tabla-elementos">
                        
                        </tbody>
                        </table>
<br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Motivo retirada:</label>
                            <select name="motivo" id="" class="form-control">
                                <option value="No obedecer una señal de prohibición (VADO)">No obedecer una señal de prohibición (VADO)</option>
                                <option value="No obedecer una señal de prohibición">No obedecer una señal de prohibición</option>
                                <option value="Estacionar en zona destinada a paso de peatones">Estacionar en zona destinada a paso de peatones</option>
                                <option value="Obstaculiza, dificulta o supone un peligro para la circulación">Obstaculiza, dificulta o supone un peligro para la circulación</option>
                              </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Lugar de la retirada:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" name="lugar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Hora de llegada grúa:</label>
                            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="" name="llegada">
                        </div><div class="form-group">
                            <label>Hora del depósito:</label>
                            <input type="time" class="form-control" id="" name="deposito">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Recibo grúa:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="isologo" accept="image/*" capture="filesystem" id="image">
                        </div>  


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y por otro lado tengo el código de ir añadiendo líneas por cada vehículo que quiero poner en el listado a enviar:

```
var tablaElementos = document.getElementById('tabla-elementos');

var txtMarca = document.getElementById('marca');
var txtModelo = document.getElementById('modelo');
var ddlColor = document.getElementById('color');
var txtMatricula = document.getElementById('matricula');

var btnAgregar = document.getElementById('agregar');

var datos = [];

function btnEditar_Click(event) {

    txtMarca.value = this.elemento.marca;
    txtModelo.value = this.elemento.modelo;
    ddlColor.value = this.elemento.color;
    txtMatricula = this.elemento.matricula;

}

function btnAgregar_Click(event) {

    var marca = txtMarca.value || '';
    var modelo = txtModelo.value || '';
    var color = ddlColor.value || '';
    var matricula = txtMatricula.value || '';

    if (!marca || !marca.trim().length) {
        alert('debe ingresar una marca');
        return;
    }
    
    if (!modelo || !modelo.trim().length) {
        alert('debe ingresar un modelo');
        return;
    }

    txtMarca.value = '';
    txtModelo.value = '';
    txtMatricula.value = '';

    txtMarca.focus();

    // JSON

    var item = {
        marca: marca.trim(),
        modelo: modelo.trim(),
        color: color,
        matricula: matricula,
        fecha: new Date()
    };

    datos.push(item);
    
    //tablaElementos.innerHTML = '';

    while (tablaElementos.childElementCount > 0) {
        tablaElementos.removeChild(tablaElementos.firstElementChild);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {

        var elemento = datos[i];

        /*
        var fila = '<tr><td>' + elemento.marca +
                    '</td><td>' + elemento.modelo +
                    '</td><td>' + elemento.color + '</td></tr>';

        tablaElementos.innerHTML += fila;
        */

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var td1 = document.createElement('td');
        var td2 = document.createElement('td');
        var td3 = document.createElement('td');
        var td4 = document.createElement('td');
        var td5 = document.createElement('td');

        tr.appendChild(td1);
        tr.appendChild(td2);
        tr.appendChild(td3);
        tr.appendChild(td4);
        tr.appendChild(td5);

        td1.textContent = elemento.marca;
        td2.textContent = elemento.modelo;
        td3.textContent = elemento.color;
        td4.textContent = elemento.matricula;

        tablaElementos.appendChild(tr);

        var nuevoBoton = document.createElement('button');
        nuevoBoton.type = 'button';
        nuevoBoton.textContent = 'Editar';
        
        nuevoBoton.addEventListener('click', btnEditar_Click);
        nuevoBoton.elemento = elemento;
        td5.appendChild(nuevoBoton);

    }

};

btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', btnAgregar_Click);
```

El caso es que los datos de esa tabla en modo Array no se pasan por POST. El resto de inputs sí se pasan.

Comment: Hola. Los datos dentro de un `td` no son enviados con el `form`. Debes meterlos dentro de un `input` para que se envíen. O, los puedes recoger de forma programática y enviarlos vía Ajax o Fetch. Esto sería mucho mejor, y estarías dando un salto cualitativo en tu código, haciéndolo más moderno.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano pero se puede mostrar esos datos en un input? no visualizo cómo sería el código para ello

Comment: Pues claro. Haces un `document.createElement('input')` para cada `td`, metes los datos dentro de ese `input` y luego metes ese `input` dentro del `td`.

Comment: La secuencia sería: `var input1 = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute('type', 'text'); input1.value=elemento.marca; var td1 = document.createElement('td'); td1.appendChild(input1); tr.appendChild(td1); /*Hacer lo mismo con los otros td*/ tablaElementos.appendChild(tr);` Y quitas `td1.textContent = elemento.marca;` y parecidos, porque el dato irá dentro del `input`, no dentro del `td`. Finalmente, como recomendación, usa [Fragmentos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment) para incorporar elementos dinámicos.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la explicación... lo he hecho pero no me llega a pasar las variables por POST, imagino que las pasa mediante array pero cuando recepciono por POST el echo me lo da en blanco. Algo creo que hago mal. No sé si en el form estoy poniendo los inputs correctamente, es decir, name="marca[]" para poder recoger esos datos como array,

Comment: Es correcto, debes poner `[]` si entrarán varios datos en cada `input`. Depura con un `var_dump($_POST);` del lado del servidor para ver lo que estás recibiendo.

Comment: @A.Cedano finalmente no lo he podido conseguir.. llevo más de tres horas dándole vueltas y probando y no me pasa los valores de los select e inputs. No sé si sobre el código que pongo arriba se puede modificar algo para que lo vea más claro porque de momento no me pasa las variables.

Comment: Revisa el código fuente en el navegador y verifica que el `form` y los elementos dentro de él se están creando correctamente.